# identificar NullPointerException

Tags: java

Estou estando JSP, e durante o teste de um DAO, me surgiu um NullPointerException aqui. No entanto, não estou conseguindo identificar o porque.

Estou usando PreparedStatement e puxando a contante "INSERIR", que eu criei, em um método. Segue o código:

```
private static final String INSERIR ="INSERT INTO produto (ds_tipo_produto, nm_produto, nr_quantidade,\"\r\n vl_preco, ds_tipo_negociacao) VALUES (? , ? , ? , ?, ?)";
private static final String ALTERAR ="UPDATE produto SET ds_tipo_produto =?, nm_produto =?, nr_quantidade=?,vl_preco=?, ds_tipo_negociacao=?) ";
private static final String EXCLUIR = "DELETE FROM produto WHERE id_produto = ?";
private static final String LISTAR_POR_CÓDIGO ="SELECT * FROM produto WHERE id_produto=?";
private static final String LISTAR_TUDO ="SELECT * FROM produto";

private static Connection conn ;
public produtoDAO() {   
    conn = ConexaoBD.getConnection();
}

public static void registrarItem(Produto p) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(INSERIR);
        ps.setString(1, p.getTipoProduto());
        ps.setString(2, p.getNomeProduto());
        ps.setInt(3, p.getQtdProduto());
        ps.setDouble(4, p.getPreco());
        ps.setString(5, p.getTipoNegociacao());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close(); 
    }
```

e aqui está minha classe teste:

```
public class teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Produto produto = new Produto();
        produto.setTipoProduto("tipo1");
        produto.setNomeProduto("item1");;
        produto.setQtdProduto(5);;
        produto.setPreco(10.00);;
        produto.setTipoNegociacao("Venda");
        produtoDAO.registrarItem(produto);

        //System.out.println(produto);
    }
}
```

O que vocês sugerem?

Comment: O começo ali deu ruim, mas espero que entendam. rsrsrs

Comment: Tenta identificar o erro exato, faz um try catch nesse método, e se der  NullPointerException, joga no console o erro, fazendo ex.getMessage();

Comment: Então, meu catch tá assim:
`catch(SQLException ex) {
   
   ex.printStackTrace();
   
  }`
  
se eu trocar SQLexception por null pointer, vai dar erro nas variáveis.

Comment: Quando da null pointer entra em SQLException ?

Comment: A classe teste chama o método, dai o método já trava na hora que atribui o preparedstatement

Comment: A minha resposta não ajudou?

Comment: Desculpa, Igor! vou verificar agora, estava ocupado, obrigado pela explicação. De fato, eu tinha esquecido da convenção da nomenclatura das classes. já já eu digo se deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Algo me diz que a classe DAO se chama `produtoDAO`.

Partindo dessa premissa, no método `main()` você faz: `produtoDAO.registrarItem(produto);`. Ao fazer isso o método estático `registrarItem()` é chamado.

Perceba que não foi criada nenhuma instância. Dessa forma o construtor não é chamado. Logo a linha que inicializa o atributo `conn` não é executada:

```
public produtoDAO() {   
    conn = ConexaoBD.getConnection();
}
```

Sendo assim, quando o método `registrarItem()` for chamado o atributo `conn` estará nulo, resultando numa `NullPointerException` na linha: `PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(INSERIR);`

---

Para resolver: faça uma instância da classe `produtoDAO` e use-a.
Se não tiver algum motivo explicito para o método `registrarItem()` ser estático, deixe-o como instância (não estético).

Ah, outra coisa: normalmente classes em Java começam com a letra maiúscula. Isso é uma convenção. Não faça `produtoDAO`. Faça `ProdutoDAO`.
Isso ajuda inclusive as pessoas entenderem seu código para te ajudarem.
Acredito que algumas pessoas pensaram que `produtoDAO` era uma variável que apontava pra uma instância de `produtoDAO` justamente porque isso é uma pratica comum: `ProdutoDAO produtoDAO = new ProdutoDAO();`